# gauge function of convex set and closures

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $C$ be a non-empty convex set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The gauge function of $C$ is defined as $\gamma(x|C) = \inf\left\{\lambda  \ge 0 | x \in \lambda C \right\}$ (Rockafellar, Convex Analysis). According to my intuition, $\gamma(\cdot |C)$ is in general different thatn $\gamma(\cdot|\operatorname{cl}(C))$, where $\operatorname{cl}(C)$ is the closure of $C$. But is it true that the closures of these two gauge functions coincide? (The epigraph of the closure of a proper convex function is the closure of the epigraph of the function, see Rockafellar).

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you reading Rockafellar because you're interested in convex optimization theory, or do you have other motivations?  Is it common for pure mathematicians to read Rockafellar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $\gamma(\cdot | C) \ge \gamma(\cdot | \operatorname{cl}(C))$ implies
$$\operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot | C)) \subset \operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot | \operatorname{cl}(C))).$$
It remains to prove
$$\operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot | C))) \supset \operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot | \operatorname{cl}(C))).$$
Let $\alpha = \gamma(x | \operatorname{cl}(C))$. Since $\operatorname{cl}(C)$ is closed, we have $x \in \alpha \, \operatorname{cl}(C)$, i.e., there is a sequence $\{c_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset C$ with $c_n \to c$ and $x = \alpha \, c$. Thus, $(\alpha, \alpha \, c_n) \in \operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot | C))$ and $(\alpha, \alpha \, c_n) \to (\alpha, x) \in \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot | C)))$. This provides $(\beta, x) \in \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot | C)))$ for all $(\beta, x) \in \operatorname{epi}(\gamma(\cdot|\operatorname{cl}(C)))$.

Comment: I have reversed the first inequality. I think that $x \in \alpha \, cl(C)$ follows since 1. $cl(C)$ is closed and 2. $C$ is convex with $0 \in C$.

Comment: For defining a gauge function, one typically assumes $0 \in C$, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional#Definition.

Comment: I have revised my answer.